# How do I have an action happen 24 hours after a specific date in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im on Rails 4, I'm creating a listing/rental site where people can list things and then other people can rent them. I'm using Stripe to handle all my payments, and I have a form set up that gets the users credit card and makes them a customer when they request to book a rental. After that, the owner of the rental can view the request and confirm or deny it. If they confirm it, the user renting gets their card charged and their money goes into holding.

When a user requests a booking, they choose a pick-up and drop-off date. I would like to have an action that calls a payout from stripe to the listings owner 24 hours after the pick up date. I am not sure how to go about this, so any suggestions are great! Of course if anyone knows of any tutorials implementing such a thing that would be awesome :).

Thanks.

Comment: Good question, many gems can be used but whenever is more stable gem and easy to use.

Answer (score 2):

Couple of things you can do

- [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job): requires a database and a running process to run scheduled jobs; You can use it on heroku as shown [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/delayed-job)
- [resque-scheduler](https://github.com/resque/resque-scheduler): requires redis and [resque](https://github.com/resque/resque) and a running process to run scheduled jobs. You can use it on heroku as shown [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/queuing-ruby-resque). Use [resque-web](https://github.com/resque/resque-web) and [resque-cleaner](https://github.com/ono/resque-cleaner) to check and handle failed jobs.
- [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever): requires access to cron jobs and your own script to be setup to run every hour or every few minutes to then pickup listings that need to be processed and then process them away. You'll need to work out a good error reporting system. Doesn't run on heroku
- [heroku scheduler](https://addons.heroku.com/scheduler): that is all managed through heroku but essentially gives you the same capabilities as `whenever`.

Resque would probably be my choice, but you should know better about your domain.

Answer (score 1):

Install the whenever gem and documentation is available here: https://github.com/javan/whenever

Then in config/scheduler.rb file mention your function name and defined in the model or as per requirement. It will be behave like CRON job but major difference is that it can run application internal function as well.

Comment: Once you run the update command it will add lines to crontab and you can check it as " crontab -l "

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of doing this.

All of which involve some sort of data store that is checked every X minutes. Within this data store you can usually set a run on time.

Checkout:

https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job

or

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq